# getting Thumbnail stream from Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, thumbnails

I have uploaded some images and documents in document and media portet of Liferay  I want to get the Thumbnail of that Images.

Folder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(repositoryId,                DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
            java.util.List l;
            l =                      DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntries(repositoryId,projectsFolder.getFolderId());

```
        for(FileEntry f:l)
        {
            JsonObject obj=new JsonObject();
            InputStream is=f.getContentStream();


        }
```

From above code i can get the normal stream of Images but i want to get the thumbnail stream.Is is possible??? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your snippet into consideration

```
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.ImageProcessorUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.DLPreviewableProcessor;

for(FileEntry f:l) {
  InputStream thumbnail = ImageProcessorUtil.getThumbnailAsStream(f.getFileVersion(), DLPreviewableProcessor.THUMBNAIL_INDEX_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: And what if i want to  get thumbnails of document files?

Comment: Other contents except images how to i get thumbnails of those contents that are stored in liferay repository????